# Remove extra tab delimiter in CSV using regex

Tags: php, regex, csv

I have a tab-delimited CSV file that looks like this:

```
Apple   10  June    Mexico
Grape   27      February    Canada
Banana      August  Peru
```

The data consist of four columns. Sometimes unnecessary tabs appears in there, so I'm removing it with this code:

```
$csv = file_get_contents($csvPath);
$pattern = '/\t+/';
$replacement = "\t";
$csv = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $csv);
```

The code solves the problem on the second row, but it also removes a tab in the third row that is supposed to stay unchanged (the second column in third row is supposed to be empty). My question, can I remove the unnecessary tab without removing tabs in empty columns? How to do that using regex?

Comment: Can your fields contain commas inside them, not just at the end? If not, and commas may appear only as separators, you may use `preg_replace('~^([^,\r\n]*),+([^,\r\n]*),+([^,\r\n]*),+([^,\r\n]*)$~m', '$1,$2,$3,$4', $s)`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0n0qKH/1).

Comment: parse csv line by line, cout commas - if commas number is greater than 3 then use your regexp for that line

Comment: @Wiktor yes some data have commas inside it. Haven't thought about it..

Comment: Then, if you cannot describe the contexts where the commas should be removed, it does not look possible to solve.

Comment: @Wiktor if it's tab delimited, is it possible to solve it? Actually the csv come as tab delimited, but it's difficult to read so I changed it to comma.

Comment: Please update the question with the tab-delimited example and explain the conditions under which the text you want to remove can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
^(.*?)\t+(.*?)\t+(.*?)\t+(.*?)$
```

with

```
\1\t\2\t\3\t\4
```

[Visualized here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jIOmU6/2).